# Can't start Android 12 AVD, but can start Android 11 AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I've been developing and testing my app using an Android 11 AVD without problems. Now i wanted to test Android 12 and created a new AVD using an Android 12 image. But when i start the AVD, it spawns a qemu process, but i don't see any window and nothing happens (even after 30 minutes). I've tried various images and reinstalling the whole SDK.

Here is a log from starting the emulator in the terminal:

```
[bblock@Manjaro emulator]$ emulator @Pixel_4_API_31
2021-09-21 13:07:46.427 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering beacon_swarm
2021-09-21 13:07:46.427 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering beacon
2021-09-21 13:07:46.427 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering scripted_beacon
2021-09-21 13:07:46.427 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering remote_loopback
2021-09-21 13:07:46.427 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering car_kit
2021-09-21 13:07:46.427 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering classic
2021-09-21 13:07:46.427 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering sniffer
2021-09-21 13:07:46.427 bluetooth - /buildbot/src/android/emu-master-dev/system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering keyboard
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))


Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_posture_requested(int) ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_posture_selection_dialog() ((null):0, (null))


cannot add library /home/bblock/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
added library ./lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

emulator: INFO: userspace-boot-properties.cpp:249: Sending adb public key [QAAAAAcE9uhJ1u1QvVBgs/XDrtc7M+IkSmH4jKcz30MqJrYsxKH2yMB3krqw7ahlbMbA176wuKBGmn/ejrTGukT9Q8sQyVwHqaKr+R4t0uoGreupf49He+9E8RIop7t0vJD92QJdcFPquJJDACywPGoPp0JhAxZyAjcyYYT2HO1UxHVI3t6U/Nqd3qvpYMc14jV/asXgEXNt4fiL3sjJILjy7r3mu/V6djANBkd8d4mZv1t3po/VNEPoNKVjyCjFe6KcW31QtON3tNg2WKDu4bSuiUI3ORXyFeSYJAgGhv2u5Mc+CO3wPI6Dkr0eAGtLBrIwdF0CuNnGJReB99FTs7L8BC44dfeouUwwS69y7vHO1zVMqo2iVMiLCFoQzvKisjJFishvCBxYgXveexcynBBiVsCbWW5WZyBeNokpjn4bpHHTB33vp79EYLxTvzURnYSwDkCFwzB+Ihs8RIjneKKuvIDAjeg2tnr67rQcQeizKeua3JlT8bfMjt5nm/fcUsW1XKEHsV1L9dg5XX5uwUEdTPmGmApEUTekQQgfJ2rZl1/S4QJgecjCFa000GaJ6YCIee1fS7wluswyAEhGEZD3K98Yh/bM2b2D3SnWHYohiKK4YPxzujou51H2WgDxbNOm0luS+mTAmAovkKNAOIcGU43KEgy//OWeQ8yL/F4wq2Wsl3hMEAEAAQA= bblock@unknown]
qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,port=36801,host=::1,nowait,nodelay,ipv6,id=modem: address resolution failed for ::1:36801: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
^C^C^CSpeicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

I'm using Manjaro, Kernel 5.14, latest Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 1):

```
address resolution failed for ::1:36801:
```

Same error here.

I solved it by temporarily disabling ipv6 for the loopback interface with the comand:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

and restart systemd-sysctl.service:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-sysctl
```

To permanently disabling ipv6, just create the file /etc/sysctl.d/40-ipv6.conf:

```
#Disable ipv6 for lo interface
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30228945)

Comment: Did you see that the error I quoted is present at the bottom of the log posted by Bastian Block? Do you also have the same problem? Is the solution I proposed not working?

Comment: @dsillman2000 is wrong. This answer does provide a solution that solves my issue which is described in the question. Thank you, S3t1.

Comment: Same question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71073999/17994624) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71991760/17994624).