# qemu-system-x86_64 : address resolution failed for ::1:46189: Name or service not known

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, qemu

I have the following problem. When I run `emulator @avdname` the following error is thrown:

```
(...)
qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,port=46189,host=::1,nowait,nodelay,ipv6,id=modem: address resolution failed for ::1:46189: Name or service not known
(...)
```

I tried to find the solution on the internet ([here](https://bobcares.com/blog/libvirt-error-unable-to-resolve-address-name-or-service-not-known/) and [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-troubleshooting-common_libvirt_errors_and_troubleshooting#sect-Migration_fails_with_Error_unable_to_resolve_address)) but still without success.

/etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   luis-HP-ProBook-450-G2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Given this is just loopback, is it absolutely vital to use ipv6? It might be an ipv6-specific issue that you could workaround by using ipv4...

Comment: The image I'm pulling up is system-images;android-31;google_apis_playstore;x86_64. In no step I choose between ipv4 or ipv6. Automatically when I am not connected to any network, when executing the command ```emulator @avdname``` the execution ends unexpectedly.

Comment: oh, it's the android emulator, not QEMU being used directly

Answer (score 13):

I don't know what causes this, but following the advice at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215231636, I can confirm that turning off IPv6 completely fixed my issue.

Temporary:
`sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`

Permanent setting: put `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or in `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` (whichever is the right way in your system).

Comment: I was stuck not being able to run the emulator on Fedora (and also Ubuntu) for 2 days; I tired so many solutions but NONE of them worked. Finally, after disabling IPv6, the emulator worked like a charm! Thank you! I wonder why would even having a problem with IPv6 would cause the emulator to not appear at all...

Comment: Thanks alot even i was facing the same problem after disabling the ipv6 my emulator works like a charm .

Comment: Same question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69268064/17994624) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69795602/17994624).

Comment: I don't agree with the answer... What if my system need IPv6 to be used? It looks like a workaround but it doesn't solve the problem. I.e. only one thing works - either emulator or IPv6. Not both... :(

Answer (score 0):

I found SIM card disabled, because `qemu-system-x86_64: Unable to connect character device modem: address resolution failed for ::1:45695: Name or service not known`

My computer Wi-Fi IPv6 is disabled.

how to fix:

1. set computer Wi-Fi IPv6 to `ignore` or `auto`
2. `sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`